# SAS LASR server Exception while importing local data

Tags: sas

i'm new to SAS and after successful installation when i'm trying to import some local .xl file it is giving the following exception, how to resolve this.Any leads will be helpful as i'm new to it. Thanks in Advance
[image: LASR EXCEPTION]

Comment: SAS has a client-server architecture. LASR is a server for big data/massive parallel processing. Is there a reason for you to use that? Also which client  are you using?

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply, we've just installed SAS Depot and using Visual Analytics when i'm trying to import local .xls file, i was getting this exception.   I've just started working on SAS so don't have much idea on it.

Comment: Indeed, SAS VA uses a SAS LASR server. I have no experience with it.

Comment: ok. Thanks a lot for your time :)